# How do I run this python file in the command prompt when I'm getting an error message

Tags: python-2.7

I created this file ex1.py and saved it in the Python27 file which is on my C drive. I'm trying to run this file in the command prompt. On my command prompt by default it is set for PS C:\Users\Ted. Next I changed the path so that it was reflective of where the file is actually located and this is the error message I got "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ex1.py"

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `ex1.py`?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Ted> PS C:\Python27>python ex1.py

Comment: If I am reading your command correctly, you do not need the `PS` before the `C:\Python27\python` argument. Also, you may not even need to provide the path to your `python.exe` if `C:\Python27` is defined appropriately as your `PATH` environment variable. In any event, try: `C:\Python27\python C:\directory\where\ex1.py`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found by changing the directory path to where the file was stored worked. So the syntax I used was cd: C:\Python 27. Once I was in that directory I could then run the file.

Comment: Glad I could had helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Anthony Forloney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166712/anthony-forloney)'s comment:

> ... you do not need the PS before the `C:\Python27\python` argument. Also, you may not even need to provide the path to your `python.exe` if `C:\Python27` is defined appropriately as your `PATH` environment variable. In any event, try: `C:\Python27\python C:\directory\where\ex1.py`

I found by changing the directory path to where the file was stored worked. So the syntax I used was `cd C:\Python 27`. Once I was in that directory I could then run the file.